# c++ software packages to solve linear systems subject to constraints

Tags: c++, software-recommendation, deal.ii

I have a finite element project based on deal.II and cmake/make as build system.

I am aware of popular libraries such as deal.II, trilinos, petsc, mumps, superlu_dist,... to solve large sparse linear systems $Cx=d$.

However, for some preprocessing tasks, I am looking for packages that allow me to solve
$Cx = d$ subject to $Ax \leq b$ (linear inequality constraints) or $Ax=b$ (linear equality constraints) or $l_b < x < u_b$ (bound constraints).

Those systems can be easily solved, for instance, in matlab using `lsqlin` function.
But I am not aware of open-source C++ libraries with that capability. NLopt, gsl,... they do not offer handling bounds or linear constraints on the parameters.

Comment: you can tackle this with any package that solves quadratic programs, such as CVXOPT [https://cvxopt.org/examples/tutorial/qp.html]

Answer (score 1):

deal.II has a [tutorial](https://dealii.org/current/doxygen/deal.II/step_41.html) showing how to solve the obstacle problem, which has one-sided bounds constraints, using an active set approach.
PETSc also has a variational inequality solver [SNESVINEWTONRSLS](https://petsc.org/release/manualpages/SNES/SNESVINEWTONRSLS/) and they also have a [tutorial](https://petsc.org/release/src/snes/tutorials/ex9.c.html) showing how to use it.
For simple bounds constraints these should work fine; for constraints of the form $Ax \le b$, it's likely that you'll need to reformulate this using a slack variable $s$ as $Ax + s = b$ with the constraint $s \ge 0$.

If you need something quick and dirty but possibly inexact you can also try a proximal method.